# Phantom JS load a page that loads content through JS, Return black screenshots jpg image

Tags: phantomjs

I am having problem to get screenshots of the website that loads through JS. I want to get the screenshots of that site but I got black screenshots .The code is working fine for other websites except this one which loads all content through js.( website is: https://signup.investorplace.com/?cid=MKT390371&eid=MKT390711&encryptedsnaid=&snaid=&step=start&assetId=AST96863)

My code is here:

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var page=webpage.create();
var system=require('system');
var url='http://'+system.args[1];

page.settings.resourceTimeout = 15000; // 15 seconds
page.open(url, function (status) {
       if (status !== 'success') {
           console.log('Unable to load the address!');
       } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('preview.jpg',{format:'jpeg',quality:'80'});
            phantom.exit();
        },3000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how you create the `url` variable, using `http` protocol

```
var url='http://'+system.args[1];
```

But your target page is served via http**s**. The `url` is bound to be incorrect.

When given the correct URL, PhantomJS will produce [a valid preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdH09.jpg)